# How to override (disable) the "submit" behaviour of a button tag inside of a form tag?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<form action="">
  <button>click</button>
</form>
```

The default behaviour of a button inside a form is to submit that form.

How can I disable the submit behaviour of that button?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Add a `type="button"` to it:

```
<button type="button">Click</button>
```

---

The types availabe are:

- "submit": Default value. Submits the form.
- "reset": Resets the form's inputs.
- "button": Does nothing.

A good reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLButtonElement

Answer (score 6):

There are occasions where you want to keep the niceties of a `submit` button (for instance, on a mobile device, where the `submit` button can be triggered from the keyboard, but only if the button is part of the form and of type `submit`). In this case what you need to do is prevent the default action of the button.

Using jQuery 1.7+ (using [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) - I highly recommend reading the documentation - there are many nuances to using `.on` that can vastly affect performance)

```
$(document).on("click", "button", "event", function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```

Using older versions of jQuery...

```
$("#button-id").bind("click", function(evt, ui) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```

Note that you can use any selector (select by class, element type etc) or an method of binding to the event (instead of [`.bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), use [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) as appropriate to your version of jquery.

Comment: A bit of an overkill for that particular question, but good to know how to use jQuery to do the exact same thing. Thanks for your input.

Comment: When you say "vastly effect performance", is it negatively or positively?

Comment: Depends on your perspective. Using it correctly makes it faster, while incorrectly makes it slower.

Answer (score 5):

This will disable via javascript

```
<button onclick='return false'>click</button>
```

But you can just define the type

```
<button type='button'>click</button>
```