# Stay on same page but process submit button

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, spring-boot

I have a controller that need to save some data on button click and stay on same page after it, but I have a problem, when I click on button nothing is saved in database, even controller is not called.

This is `controller:`

```
@PostMapping("/savedAdventureHolidays/post/{adventureHolidayId}")
public UserProfile saveAdventureHolidayElement(@PathVariable(value = "adventureHolidayId") String adventureHolidayId) {
    UserProfile comment = new UserProfile();

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String username = authentication.getName();

    return adventureHolidaysRepository.findById(adventureHolidayId).map(post -> {
        comment.setAdventureHolidaysList(Collections.singletonList(post));
        comment.setLoggedUserId(username);
        comment.setSavedHolidayTitle(adventureHolidaysRepository.findById(adventureHolidayId).get().getTitle());
        logger.info("Calling method.");
        return userProfileRepository.save(comment);
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("PostId " + adventureHolidayId + " not found"));
}
```

This is `HTML button:`

```
 <form id="tweet-form" th:action="@{/api/userProfile/savedAdventureHolidays} + '{/post/}'+ ${randomSummerCamp.id}"
              th:method="post">
            <input id="submit-form" class="form-control" type="button" value="Submit" />
        </form>
```

And this is JS:

```
$('#submit-form').on('click', function() {
var form = $('#tweet-form');
let post;
$.ajax({
    url: form.attr('action'),
    data: form.serialize(),
    type: post,
    success: function(result) {
        // Do something with the response.
        // Might want to check for errors here.
    }, error: function(error) {
        // Here you can handle exceptions thrown by the server or your controller.
    }
})
})
```

No errors in IDE, no errors in console log, any idea how I can fix this, or someone already has something like this and can give me a advice how to fix it? Trying for couple of days and I'm really feel demotivated, thanks.

Comment: Did you already ask this or a similar question earlier today?

Comment: Yes, I asked already, but there was almost no help so I thought maybe now someone see question and give help. I was trying to fix this by myself for previous three days and I'm really desperate for help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override (disable) the "submit" behaviour of a button tag inside of a form tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100696/how-to-override-disable-the-submit-behaviour-of-a-button-tag-inside-of-a-for)

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I already came to it but no

Comment: Lmao, this site... As I said that question does not answer my question, its not even similar